# Delphi 10.1 Berlin Fast Report - Show Multiple Records in One Page

Tags: delphi, fastreport, delphi-10.1-berlin

Below is the design of my report.

[image]

When clicking the preview button, it shows one record every page.

[image]

[image]

How to make it display multiple records until the page is fully occupied, and then the next record will be on the next page? I want something like the image below.

[image]

Comment: @KenWhite -> I have been always reading the documentation. My output just goes different from what it says.

Comment: Then you've missed something. You should read again. We can't see what you've done based on images.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have set the StartNewPage property flag on your MasterData1.

Click that band with the righ button and uncheck the Start New Page of its Menu.

Comment: I recommend you to save that report on a file as backup and start a new blank report, without any hidden properties (like that StartNewPage flag) set on previous trials. Your report is very simple, and leaving the bands by default it already should work as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining Report DataSet, define MasterData1 DataSet. 
Right click on MasterData1, Edit... select the your DataSet and set the value of **Number of Records** to 0. Probably this property is set with 1.